# Book about psychic child, Immortals (men who drain boys for vitality), a boy's mother is reanimated as a shell

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a book from my childhood. Read sometime in the early 1990s. The title was something like "the Prophet" or "the Seer". I think the cover was green or blue with a clam shell on it.

I remember several "scenes" within the plot:

- A beach with two crucified boys being forcibly exposed to a magic clam to trigger precognition.
- A society in which the Immortals, all men, suck vitality from boys in some magic way, leaving them frail and withered. The boy changes his "energy" to female and so poisons one of them.
- The empress on top of the emperors hareem decreeing she will wall in all the concubines. The Immortals confront her there, but fall to pieces as they fight. She says something along the lines of "it has been a good day, I have seen the Immortals die".
- Another boy loses his mother who is reanimated by a mage as a mindless shell (NOT a flesh eating zombie). The mage warns the boy beforehand that while he can make the body live the mind/soul will be gone. The boy insists though.
- It might be the title's seer or the boy above, but his hair grows into a "nail" that covers his face like a plate, then later drops off.

I simply cannot find the book, probably because "seer" and "prophet" are so widely used title words.

Comment: FWIW, a trawl through ISFDb for novels published before 1995 with "prophet," "seer," "oracle," "soothsayer," "sibyl" (and a couple other synonyms) in the title yields no stories that match any of the given plot points.  (I didn't have any luck turning up a cover that matched that description either.)

Comment: Thank you for trying. Its so annoying. I know I have read this book...

Comment: I am guessing that this was not originally in English -- could it have been published in, for example, Turkey?

Comment: See if this looks familiar: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TalesFromTheFlatEarth?from=Literature.DeathsMaster

Comment: Or maybe this one: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TortallUniverse